# SDL or OpenGL unexpected behavior (Process termiated with status -1073741510 (o minutes, 6 seconds))

Tags: c++, opengl, sdl-2

I have the following code and it compiles successfully but when I execute the program the following message appears.

> Process terminated with status -1073741510 (0 minute(s), 3 second(s))

What am I doing wrong?

here's the code:

```
#include <SDL.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#ifdef WIN32
    #define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN
    #include <windows.h>
#endif // WIN32

#if defined(__APPLE__) && defined(__MACH__)
    #include <OpenGL/gl.h>
    #include <OpenGL/glu.h>
#else
    #include <GL/gl.h>
    #include <GL/glut.h>
#endif // defined

const GLsizei windowWidth = 500;
const GLsizei windowHeight = 500;


GLfloat cubeRotateX = 45.0f;
GLfloat cubeRotateY = 45.0f;

const Uint8 *keys = NULL;

GLvoid establishProjectionMatrix(GLsizei width, GLsizei height)
{
    glViewport(0, 0, width, height);

    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);

    glLoadIdentity();

    gluPerspective(50.0f, (GLfloat)width / (GLfloat)height, 0.1f, 200.0f);
}

GLvoid initGL(GLsizei width, GLsizei height)
{
    establishProjectionMatrix(width, height);

    glShadeModel(GL_SMOOTH);

    glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);

    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    glDepthFunc(GL_LEQUAL);

    glHint(GL_PERSPECTIVE_CORRECTION_HINT, GL_NICEST);
    glEnable(GL_PERSPECTIVE_CORRECTION_HINT);

}

GLvoid displayFPS(GLvoid)
{
    static long lastTime = SDL_GetTicks();
    static long loops = 0;
    static GLfloat fps = 0.0f;

    int newTime = SDL_GetTicks();

    if (newTime - lastTime > 100)
    {
        float newFPS = (float)loops / float(newTime - lastTime) * 1000.0f;

        fps = (fps + newFPS) / 2.0f;

        char title[80];
        printf(title, "OpenGL Demo - %2f", fps);

        SDL_SetWindowTitle(NULL, title);

        lastTime = newTime;

        loops = 0;
    }

    loops++;

}

GLvoid drawScene(GLvoid)
{
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadIdentity();

    glTranslatef(0, 0, -5.0f);
    glRotatef(cubeRotateX, 1, 0, 0);
    glRotatef(cubeRotateY, 0, 1, 0);

    //draw cube
    glBegin(GL_QUADS);
        //top face
        glColor3f(1.0f, 0.5f, 0.0f);
        glVertex3f(1.0f,  1.0f, -1.0f);
        glVertex3f(-1.0f, 1.0f, -1.0f);
        glVertex3f(-1.0f, 1.0f,  1.0f);
        glVertex3f(1.0f,  1.0f,  1.0f);

        //bottom face
        glColor3f(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
        glVertex3f( 1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f);
        glVertex3f(-1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f);
        glVertex3f(-1.0f, -1.0f,  1.0f);
        glVertex3f( 1.0f, -1.0f,  1.0f);

        //front face
        glColor3f(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
        glVertex3f( 1.0f,  1.0f,  1.0f);
        glVertex3f(-1.0f,  1.0f,  1.0f);
        glVertex3f(-1.0f, -1.0f,  1.0f);
        glVertex3f( 1.0f, -1.0f,  1.0f);

          //back face
        glColor3f(1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
        glVertex3f( 1.0f,  1.0f,  -1.0f);
        glVertex3f(-1.0f,  1.0f,  -1.0f);
        glVertex3f(-1.0f, -1.0f,  -1.0f);
        glVertex3f( 1.0f, -1.0f,  -1.0f);

          //left face
        glColor3f(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
        glVertex3f(-1.0f,  1.0f,   1.0f);
        glVertex3f(-1.0f,  1.0f,  -1.0f);
        glVertex3f(-1.0f, -1.0f,  -1.0f);
        glVertex3f(-1.0f, -1.0f,   1.0f);

          //right face
        glColor3f(1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
        glVertex3f( 1.0f,  1.0f,  1.0f);
        glVertex3f( 1.0f,  1.0f,  1.0f);
        glVertex3f( 1.0f, -1.0f,  1.0f);
        glVertex3f( 1.0f, -1.0f,  1.0f);
    glEnd();

    glFlush();


    displayFPS();
}

GLboolean checkKeys(GLvoid)
{
    static long lastTime =  SDL_GetTicks();

    const GLfloat speed = 1.0f;
    const long updateTime = 10;

    if (keys[SDLK_ESCAPE])
        return true;

    long newTime = SDL_GetTicks();

    if (newTime - lastTime > updateTime)
    {
        if(keys[SDLK_LEFT])
        cubeRotateY -= speed;
        if(keys[SDLK_RIGHT])
        cubeRotateY += speed;
        if(keys[SDLK_UP])
        cubeRotateX -= speed;
        if(keys[SDLK_DOWN])
        cubeRotateX += speed;
    }

    return false;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])

{

    SDL_Window* window = SDL_CreateWindow("SDL2_Demo",SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, windowWidth, windowHeight,SDL_WINDOW_OPENGL);



    SDL_GL_SetSwapInterval(1);

    SDL_GL_SwapWindow(window);

    if (SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO) < 0)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Unable to initialize SDL %s", SDL_GetError());
    }   exit(1);

    if (&window == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Unable to iCreate OpenGL scene %s", SDL_GetError());
        exit(2);
    }




    initGL(windowWidth, windowHeight);

    int done = 0;

    while (!done)
    {
        SDL_Event event;
        while(SDL_PollEvent(&event))
        {
            drawScene();
            if (event.type == SDL_QUIT)
                done = 1;

                keys = SDL_GetKeyboardState(NULL);
        }

        if (checkKeys())
            done = 1;

    }

    SDL_Quit();

    return 1;
    }
```

Comment: `if (&window == NULL)` pretty sure this should be just `if (window == NULL)`. I would also put this check right after initializing window. Also its been a while since i used SDL but im pretty sure youre supposed to call SDL_init before calling anything else from SDL

Comment: `SDL_Init` should be called before all other `SDL_`-instructions. `exit(1);` should be in the condition.

Comment: thanks for your help I removed the & from the (&window == NULL) as you suggested me and did the SDL_Init call before as well. also I noticed that I left a line of code outside the if condition in the SDL_Init. and the problem disappears. everything compiles properly again but this time the program starts broken showing nothing for a few seconds and then closes again giving the following message "Process returned -1073741819 (0xC0000005)"

Comment: SDL_SwapWindow should be in the loop.

Comment: Ok, I'm new in this topic, where exactly Should I put this line of code?

Comment: I believe what is happening is that you have SDL_GetKeyboardState(NULL) inside of the event loop, meaning that the keys pointer only gets initialized to a value when there is an event. If the keys pointer is uninitialized and you call checkKeys(), you will be indexing invalid memory. Can you move the SDL_GetKeyboardState(NULL) call outside and just after the SDL_PollEvent(&event) call? Another solution is to call SDL_GetKeyboardState(NULL) before the main loop begins.

Comment: Jaan I tried your solutions (and the other ones) but didn't work yet, what else can I do?